# Google OAuth 2 authorization - custom User model. Error: User has no field named 'username'

Tags: python, django, oauth

I'm trying to make the authorization via Google. I use a custom user model with an email as a username field.

Once I login, I choose the email I want to login with. Then I`ve got yellow screen with an error "FieldDoesNotExist at /accounts/google/login/callback/
User has no field named 'username'". If anyone can help me, I will appreciate it very much.

**My models:**

```
# users/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=254)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Ваше имя")
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=30, help_text="Ваша фамилия")
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='Ваш телефон')
    status = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=3, choices=TYPE_OF_CLIENT, default=POTENTIAL)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

**My settings:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]

SITE_ID = 1
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = None


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
```

**URL PATTERNS**

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**My Google URI settings**

[image]

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

```
SITE_ID = 1
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'users.forms.CreationForm'}
```

Comment: It works!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much!